# How can I show the windows file explorer in the RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I would like to create a Eclipse RCP application, in which I need to show the Windows file Explorer in the View. Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to show the explorer? wouldn't it be sufficient to display the contents  of the file system in a standard SWT widget?

There's a [tutorial on using JFace and SWT to create a file explorer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecgui1/) you might find useful.